# How do I design a torrent application?

Tags: .net, wpf, architecture, bittorrent

I was curious as to the "correct" architecture of a torrent application; with WPF as the front end?

Comment: I can't imaging it being much different from a any other application? What exactly are you interested in?

Comment: How do you implement the networking/tcp streaming?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are .NET classes out there for handling torrent exchanges - a place to start might be to take a look at the layouts they're using and the bug tracking systems the developers use and see what the complaints are - that may give you an idea of what design they've chosen and where it's fallen short. From there, you can look at things you might do differently when designing your own system.

For starters, here are two in .NET:

- http://projects.qnetp.net/projects/show/monotorrent
- http://writtorrent.sourceforge.net/